# Append métodos em uma lista - Python

Tags: python

Eu tentei adcionar 4 métodos numa lista(methodList):

```
def setVar(self, number):
    self.var = number

methodList = list()

for y in range(4):
    methodList.append(setVar(self, y))
```

e a função não funciona:

```
>>> self.var = 0
>>> methodList[1]
>>> print(self.var)
0
```

se funcionasse seria assim:

```
>>> self.var = 0
>>> methodList[1]
>>> print(self.var)
1
```

ai eu printei a função pra ver:

```
>>> print(methodList[1])
None
```

Onde eu errei?

Comment: Esse primeiro código, você executou ele somente uma vez, e antes de tentar esse código seguinte no console, certo?

Comment: sim, na verdade foi tudo no código, só to usando as setas pra representar o meu problema, mas não tem erro de ordem nas linhas

Comment: O que exatamente você pretendia fazer, então? No seu loop, cada chamada do método atribui o `var` do objeto `self`, sobrescrevendo o valor anterior. Então, quando você faz `self.var = 0` você sobrescreve ele mais uma vez. Você queria que cada valor fosse pra uma posição da lista? (se sim, ver [a resposta do Cigano](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87797/215)) Ou era alguma outra coisa que pretendia (por exemplo, ao chamar `methodList[1]` de alguma forma que o efeito colateral fosse alterar `self.var`)? Me parece que você tentou fazer uma aplicação parcial de funções, mas não tenho certeza...

Comment: sim, queria tentar aplicar o methodList[1] e chamar o setVar(1), mas não estava conseguindo, o cigano ajudou, obrigado a todos

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo nada (pois se sua lista chama `methodList`, por que ela guarda valores?), mas de todo modo deixei uma resposta assumindo o segundo caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função não imprime nada. Por isso não retorna nada no `print`.

Fiz algumas correções:

```
def setVar(number):
    var = number
    return var

methodList = list()

for y in range(4):
    methodList.append(setVar(y))

print(methodList[1])
```

Não precisa usar `self` pro seu exemplo porque você não especificou uma classe.

[Veja aqui funcionando](http://pythonfiddle.com/poc-for-httpptstackoverflowcomquestions87792append_mc3a9todos_em_uma_l).

Comment: estou com um probleminha maior agora, mas é a mesma coisa(quase): self.canvasButtonCommands.append(setMusics(self, genreDirectory[a])) --------- self.canvasButtonCommands[0] não faz nada, porém o código dele ta escrito pra fazer...

Comment: Outro problema merece outra pergunta, certo?

Comment: não posso criar uma pergunta antes de 90 minutos '-', da um help plz, acho que tem haver com o [a]

Comment: Tem certeza de que não faz nada? Já tentou colocar um `print` dentro do método pra conferir?

Comment: já descobri o erro, toda vez que eu faço isso: self.canvasButtonCommands.append(setMusics(self, genreDirectory[a])) ---- ele chama a função, mas era só pra dar append

Comment: Faça o Append sem parâmetros. Use os parâmetros na hora de chamar. Se precisar, use uma estrutura auxiliar com o método e os parâmetros separados.

Answer (score 3):

Se o que você quer é **fixar** alguns argumentos de um método (como sua lista chama `methodList`, imagino que você queira guardar nela métodos, não valores) você pode usar [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Nela você estabelece um número fixo de argumentos, e recebe de volta uma "função parcial":

```
def setVar(self, number):
    self.var = number

methodList = list()

for y in range(4):
    methodList.append(functools.partial(setVar, self, y))

self.var = 0
methodList[1]() # self.var agora deve ser 1
```

Comment: Muito legal esse `functools`. Não conhecia.